# Session not working for first time, from second time it works

Tags: php, session

I don't know what is the problem. When I do login for first time after deleting all history and cookies and cache, it doesn't set session to redirected page. But when I do login for second time, session is set to redirected page. Here id the code of First & second page.

First Page

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/connection.php');
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$data=mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "select * from  user_registration where email='$email' and password='$password' ");
$data1=mysqli_num_rows($data);
$val=mysqli_fetch_array($data);

if($data1>0)
{
   $_SESSION['user_id']=$val['user_id'];
   echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";

}
else
{
    echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";

}
?>
```

Second Page

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $val=$_SESSION['user_id'];
  echo $val;
?>
```

Comment: Wait. `mysqli_query()` before creating the connection? Also, the SQL is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: You need a `session_start()` in your first page as well, preferably as the first call you make. You cannot / should not be accessing `$_SESSION` without calling session_start() first.

Comment: Yeah it's there in first page, sorry forgot to mention that. session_start(); in first page & at the top of the page

Comment: mysqli_query() connection is there. I haven't mention that. Databse connection no problem, only with session

Comment: @ImranHussain Did you find solution ?. I am facing same problem. Can U helpme plz?

Comment: @JaykumarPatil, I've changed my on-line server. Now no problem

Answer (score 2):

> **session_start(); should be at the very top of both scripts!**

Session variables are saved on server and assigned a unique code that are passed to browser in cookies.

Because the cookies are set by the **headers** they need to be sent before anything else!

Even a whitespace at the top of your script may cause session cookie to be not properly set on browser side.

So always start the both scripts like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Rest of the code....
```

It looks like they are on top on your question but I think you edited question later to put there.

That's the only reason sessions are not working the first time and they are working on second time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of the echo use

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

***EDIT***

also`session_start` should be declared at the top of the first page because you cant set a session that doesn't exist in the context if you were running it in a console environment you would receive the following error
`"$_SESSION['user_id'] does not exist in the current context"`

Comment: Still have that problem. But I have noticed, in different server and in localhost it is working.

Answer (score 0):

same happening here. is php 5.6 is super strange problem. on some pages work normaly and on one dont. First request is like dont get recognized.. :)
for example: set
#when page load set:
$_SESSION['a']=0;

#then with JS requests increase $_SESSION['a']+=1; and this start working on third request...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30118503)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).